# Is there a way to tell manifest merger not to add path data to intent-filter

Tags: android, intentfilter, android-architecture-navigation, android-navigation-graph

I'm using navigation component and navigation graph for handling deeplinks. I've added deeplinks to my destinations like below

```xml
<deepLink app:uri="example://foo" />
```

Intent Filter [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters) mentions:

> If a filter specifies a scheme and an authority but no path, all URIs with the same scheme and authority pass the filter, regardless of their paths.

According to this, a uri like `example://foo` should match my deeplink. But manifest merger adds this line to my intent filter, even if don't add any path to my uri:

```xml
<data android:path="/" />
```

So only a `example://foo/` is matched. Is there a way to tell manifest merger or navigation graph to remove this data element from my intent filter?

Comment: "all URIs with the same scheme and authority pass the filter, regardless of their paths." means your pathless intent filter also matches `example://foo/anything`, which is not what your `app:uri` says it should match

Answer (score 1):

Android does not allow you to create an `intent-filter` that matches **only** no path at all: it is impossible to write an intent-filter that matches `example://foo` but not `example://foo/something_random`.

As per [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132651315#comment3), this is intentional: using a pathless uri like `app:uri="example://foo"` means you want to match exactly that empty path - i.e., `/` and not match every single path with that authority and scheme.

Comment: thanks ian. I understand what you mean. But since we only use scheme and host this should not be a problem for us. This is also the case for us when we didn't use navigation component. We added `intent-filter`s to our manifest like `example://screenA` `example://screenB` and that worked for us.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this annoying thing.

I don't agree with the last answer since you can simply create your own `intent-filter` that only declare scheme and host.

I consider it a bug in the `nav-graph` tag processing (the one you nest in you `activity` tag).

Simple remove:

```
<nav-graph android:value="@navigation/your_nav_graph" />
```

And replace it with intent filter you create manually:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

    <data
        android:host="foo"
        android:scheme="example" />

</intent-filter>
```

I know I'm basically telling you to not-use auto `intent-filter` creation navigation feature but it's the only way that I found that navigation component accepts

Comment: I don't really want to handle deeplinks manually. That's one of the reasons why we use navigation component. Our simple solution is adding "/" at the end of host string.

Comment: I can respect that :). In my case the actual link could not be changed so I had no choice. Good Luck.